# How to run KotlinScriptEngine on Android app

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build an Android app, in which user would write a Kotlin expression involving 2 input Ints, a & b.

[AppScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4ol6.png)

The expression written by user will then be embedded into a Kotlin script (in String form) and executed by passing in custom inputs to get the desired output.

Simplified code representation :

```kotlin
val expression = // Input expression by user
val a, b = // Input Ints by user
val script = "fun x(a: Int, b: Int) = $expression; x($a, $b) 
// Run script using KotlinScriptEngine
```

While running this app, I get a runtime error :

```kotlin
Accessing hidden field Lsun/security/util/SecurityConstants;->GET_CLASSLOADER_PERMISSION:Ljava/lang/RuntimePermission; (unsupported, linking, allowed)
W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getAndAddInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)I (max-target-r, reflection, denied)
W  Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getAndAddInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)I (max-target-r, reflection, denied)
W  javax.script.ScriptException: ERROR Unable to initialize repl compiler:
W    ERROR java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAndAddInt [class java.lang.Object, long, int]: java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAndAddInt [class java.lang.Object, long, int]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize repl compiler:
W    ERROR java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAndAddInt [class java.lang.Object, long, int]: java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAndAddInt [class java.lang.Object, long, int]
W   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.asJsr223EvalResult(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:104)
```

- After research I found out that starting A12 several such Non-SDK references `getAndAddInt()` have been blocked ([Reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/non-sdk-12#new-blocked))
- I think the Kotlin Compiler is not working on Android. In fact, I found an [OPEN Kotlin issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33560/Support-Kotlin-Embedded-Compiler-Scripting-on-Android) raised for this. But people have succeeded in doing this. Here are 2 Android apps that compile and execute Kotlin code on device : 1. [Offline Kotlin IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.xbd.kotlin) 2. [Code Assist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tyron.code) (Android Studio for Android)

---

**Code Info**

- I’m using 34 targetSdk, so non-SDK ref blocked in A12 (SDK 30) won’t work. But one of the apps that work - Code Assist (mentioned above), uses 32 targetSdk, still it works for them.
- Gradle Dependencies used by me ([Complete code](https://github.com/LavishSwarnkar/KtScript-on-android/blob/main/app/build.gradle.kts#L79-L83))

```kotlin
implementation("io.apisense:rhino-android:1.0")
implementation(kotlin("scripting-jsr223"))
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable")
```

- My simplified code that executes the script ([Complete code](https://github.com/LavishSwarnkar/KtScript-on-android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/streamliners/ktscript/MainActivity.kt#L100-L137))

```kotlin
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

val engineManager = ScriptEngineManager()
val engine = engineManager.getEngineByExtension("kts")
engine.eval(kotlinCode)
```

---

This is just a simplified example, if this works - I have bigger usecase in mind. Any help in making this work is highly appreciated. Thank you for your time!